# SVN remains in conflict?

Tags: svn

How do I get this directory out of conflict? I don't care if it's resolved using "theirs" or "mine" or whatever...

```
PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject> svn ci -m "gr"
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: 'C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject\addons' remains in conflict

PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject> svn resolve --accept working C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject\addons
Resolved conflicted state of 'C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject\addons'

PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject> svn ci -m "grr"
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Commit item 'addons' has copy flag but an invalid revision

PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject> svn update
   C addons
svn: Can't move 'addons\debug_toolbar\templates\debug_toolbar\.svn\tmp\entries' to 'addons\debug_toolbar\templates\debug
_toolbar\.svn\entries': The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject> svn cleanup

PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject> svn update
Skipped 'addons'
At revision 51.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1

PS C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject> svn ci -m "grrr"
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: 'C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\myproject\addons' remains in conflict
```

Comment: the answer is: [svn resolved filename]

do this rather than the accepted solution.

Comment: @TravisSchneeberger the accepted solution is fine 

Comment: `svn resolved `*filename* doesn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 484, accepted):

Give the following command:

```
svn resolved <filename or directory that gives trouble>
```

(Thanks to @Jeremy Leipzig for this answer in a comment)

Comment: Seriously, if you don't care how it's resolved (maybe you're just going to delete it anyway) this is the right answer.

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. The error will probably arise again at the next commit.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it works for me!  You must in your svn root repo, you can use this command!

Comment: For those saying this doesn't really fix anything, you're only partly right. Sometimes you need to run "svn resolved" on the parent directory, all the way up to the root of the application. Then check it with another "svn up". The **problem** is an "issue" with SVN where if you manually copy a file from one working tree to another identical working tree, and on "update" or "commit" SVN gets confused to find the file is there already. I would call this a "bug" but I'm sure others would call it "user-error."

Answer (score 275):

Ok here's how to fix it:

```
svn remove --force filename
svn resolve --accept=working  filename
svn commit
```

more details are at: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html

Comment: If you are working with the Eclipse IDE, you can also apply my "non command line" solution, which I described in a separate answer below.

Comment: using svn 1.7.4, svn help resolved states that it "has been deprecated in favor of running 'svn resolve --accept working'."

Answer (score 42):

For me only **revert --depth infinity** option fixed 
Svn's directory remains in confict problem:

```
svn revert --depth infinity "<directory name>"
svn update "<directory name>"
```

Comment: to revert a whole directory of files or a file does not exist anymore

Comment: To resolve the conflict of locally deleted files which exists on the server, this option worked..

Comment: Thanks a lot. "svn revert --depth infinity ." worked for me and restored deleted files, which didn't reappear just with "svn up"

Comment: Indeed, works actually quite fine !

Answer (score 18):

1. svn resolve
2. svn cleanup
3. svn update

..these three svn CLI commands in this sequence while cd-ed into the correct directory worked for me.

Comment: @Elad Tabak: In my case I had to do it to the parent directory of the file giving me trouble, this might be what you ran into

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the Eclipse IDE and stumble upon this error when committing, here's an in-tool solution for you. I'm using Subclipse, but the solution for Subversive could be similar.

What you maybe didn't notice is that there is an additional symbol on the conflicting file, which marks the file indeed as "conflicted".

Right-click on the file, choose "Team" and "Edit conflicts...". Choose the appropriate action. I merged the file manually on text-level before, so I took the first option, which will take the current state of your local copy as "resolved solution". Now hit "OK" and that's it.

The conflicting symbol should have disappeared and you should be able to commit again.

Comment: Also, in case of directory conflict, you can do "Team->Show Tree Conflicts" and then review all those conflicts and mark them as Resolved (in a separate "SVN Tree Conflicts" window)

Answer (score 6):

One more solution below,

If the entire folder is removed and SVNis throwing the error "admin file .svn is missing", the following will be used to resolve the conflict to working state.

```
svn resolve --accept working "file / directory name "
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the following command in order to remove conflict using command line

```
svn revert "location of conflict folder" -R
svn cleanup
svn update
```

for reverting current directory

```
svn revert . -R
```

Comment: Hahahaha, no don't do this. It'll do bad things.

Comment: It would obviously revert your changes

Comment: it actually works for some problems like conflict and could only resolve via cli

Answer (score 4):

**Instructions for Tortoise SVN**

Navigate to the directory where you see this error. 
If you do not have any changes perform the following

a. Right click and do a 'Revert' 
b. Select all the files 
c. Then update the directory again

Answer (score 3):

If you have trouble resolving (like me) and you cannot delete and update the resources because you have made many changes on them, plus you are using eclipse subversive instead of native client, follow these steps:

1. make a copy of your entire project dir
2. perform team>disconnect within eclipse, and choose to delete the svn metadata
3. then choose team>share project, and point to the very same folder that your project resides in
4. choose yes, and commit everything (you may want to exclude some very local resources, like configuration files)
5. if you have deleted or moved some resources prior to your first commit trial, delete those old resources (they should have doubled up, one in old location, one in new) and commit those deletions.

You're done.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the proper solution is:

```
(1) backup your-file/your-directory
(2) svn revert your-file/your-directory
(3) svn update your-file/your-directory
(4) Merge the backup your-file/your-directory to the updated one.
(5) svn ci -m "My work here is done"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, this is how it was solved

xyz@ip :~/formsProject_SVN$ svn **resolved** formsProj/templates/search

Resolved conflicted state of 'formsProj/templates/search'

Now update your project

xyz@ip:~/formsProject_SVN$ svn update

Updating '.':

Select: (mc) keep affected local moves,
        (r) mark resolved (breaks moves), (p) postpone,
        (q) quit resolution, (h) help: **r** (select "r" option to resolve)

Resolved conflicted state of 'formsProj/templates/search'

Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 0 remaining (and 1 already resolved)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on linux, but I couldn't fix it with the accepted answer. I was able to solve it by using `cd` to go to the correct folder and then executing:

```
svn remove --force filename  
syn resolve --accept=working filename  
svn up
```

That's all.

Comment: In the second line, it is `svn` not `syn`