# svn 1.8 conflict : local file delete, incoming file edit upon update

Tags: svn, conflict

I deleted locally a file to have the server's version. When I try `svn up` I get the error `Tree conflict on file : local file delete, incoming file edit upon update`.

The problem is that in the options of conflict's resolution I don't have `tc (theirs conflict)`, I have only `mc (mine conflict)`

I have tried `svn resolved` mentioned in this discussion [SVN remains in conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406469/svn-remains-in-conflict) but It didn't work

Is there any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is how I solved the problem. I don't know if this is the short way but it worked:

`delete` the file in the server.
`re-add` it + `commit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the file with:

```
svn revert <local file>
```

and then

```
svn up
```

Answer (score 0):

how I resolved that ==> 
svn up file
svn delete file 
rm file 
svn resolved file